# What to put as swf file in TableTools

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datatables, tabletools

I'm a very new programmer with no experience with tabletools or swf paths whatsoever. I'm trying to implement Table Tools to print/export/etc but so far only print is working for me. Most solutions have said that means the swf path is incorrect. But I have no idea what to put as my swf path. Could anybody please help? Sorry for such a basic question. :(

Here are my plugins and script for dataTables:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can browse `tabletools` files available for `cdn` here: [datatable tabletools plugin files](https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/)

by visiting the link you will find version list, click one for example [2.2.2](https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/)

so scroll down to the bottom and see magic:

**swf**

> //cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf
>       //cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf